# Codeigniter error log file shows errors, but app works fine without error msg on screen - why?

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging, error-handling

Why would codeigniter show errors in `application/logs` such as

```
ERROR - 2011-12-31 11:43:36 --> Severity: Warning  --> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() /var/www/example.com/htdocs/application/views/home/home_vw.php 53


ERROR - 2011-12-31 11:43:36 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined variable: questions /var/www/example.com/htdocs/application/views/home/home_vw.php 53
```

if the methods to which they point to work fine --- and there are no error messages on screen?

My index.php is set at

`error_reporting(E_ALL);`

and config

`$config['log_threshold'] = 1;`

Any ideas about the reason for this behavior?

Comment: PHP is probably configured with display_errors off and log_errors on.  That's usually considered the best practice for production servers.

Comment: but what to do about CI saying a variable is undefined -- when in fact it is defined and showing properly in the front end?

Comment: The variable being empty is not the same as it being undefined.  In both cases they will display as empty strings in the output, but the former will trigger E_NOTICE messages.  The fact that you don't see them is purely down to display_errors being off, not because they're not happening.

Comment: Perhaps you could add the controller and view to the question...

Comment: thanks for the insight @GordonM - but my problem is that var_dump and print_r for variables/arguments that CI labels as undefined/invalid actually return as NOT empty or undefined - so I don't now what to do in order to stop this logging from happening without affecting logging of real errors - any suggestions?

Comment: `unset ($foo); var_dump ($foo); $foo = 'bar'; var_dump ($bar);` Just because it's undefined at the point where the notice is emitted, doesn't mean it's undefined at the point where you output it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned errors are `Warning` and `Notice`, these are not Fatal Error which prevents script from executing further. So you have probability that:

**1.** Your page is redirecting to a different page so this error warnings disappear before getting printed.

**2.** The warning is printed but you can't see it, it can happen when it is printed within HTML comments or it is behind any `div` or so, try `view-source` to detect in that case.

**3.** It can also happen when you suppress errors by using [@ sign](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).